# Is the first stall of a public restroom the cleanest?

Tags: environmental-health, hygiene, public-health

I have read so during a quick search on google, are there proofs for this theory?

Comment: I thought Mythbusters found this claim notable enough so that they conducted an actual experiment, as well as also finding additional material on the subject.

Comment: anecdotally - at my office, 'Trap 1' has the reputation of being the absolute worst...dunno if that helps your theory :-)

Comment: I thought so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2013_season)#Stall_Number_1